# How to INSERT into with nth number of values sqlite

Tags: javascript, sqlite

So i'm trying to insert data into a sqlite database from the constructor:

```
var EventData = function(ID, Name, StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime, Location, Notes){
  this.type = "event";
  this.id = ID;
  this.name = Name;
  this.startDate = StartDate;
  this.startTime = StartTime;
  this.endDate = EndDate;
  this.endTime = EndTime;
  this.location = Location;
  this.notes = Notes;
};
EventData.prototype.count = function(){
  return Object.keys(this).length;
};
```

And I want to call this function that will put this "Data" into this "database":

```
var InsertData = function(database, data){
  var dataArray = Object.keys(data);
  var ins = database.prepare("INSERT into "+data.type+" values(?)");
  for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    ins.run(data[dataArray[i]]);
  }
  ins.finalize();
};
```

when I run this code It stops at:

```
ins.run(data[dataArray[i]]);
```

expecting 8 values but getting 1.

**UPDATE**
The above code inserts multiple rows, I want to insert multiple Values without knowing the length IE: values(?1, ?2, ... ?n).

```
var InsertData = function(database, data){
  database.run("INSERT into "+data.type+" values(?)",data);
};
```

So how would I (if possible) INSERT with an unknown number of values?

Comment: Why don't you use this syntax for multiple inserts:

`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (.., .., ..),
    (.., .., ..)`

Or if you wish to stick with your syntax, try using a `foreach` loop as your index values might not be in order.

Comment: edited post to better ask the question, I want something that will insert nth number of values, not nth number of rows.